PyJWT installed but keey getting: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jwt'
My Django project was working fine. Then followed the steps to implement Auth0 into my project, which I have setup on my frontend successfully.
I followed all of these steps:
https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/django/01-authorization
Running in Python 3.9.6 ('.venv': Pipenv) ./.venv/bin/python
Trying installing requirements in all environments as well

I even updated requirements.txt to the most modern versions to see if it was a compatibility issue. When I run python manage.py runserver I get
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/chasesheaff/teachr-backend/teachr/urls.py", line 23, in <module>
    path('', include('auth0authorization.urls')),
  File "/Users/chasesheaff/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 38, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/chasesheaff/teachr-backend/auth0authorization/urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/Users/chasesheaff/teachr-backend/auth0authorization/views.py", line 5, in <module>
    import jwt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jwt'

pip freeze  yields this result
asgiref==3.7.2
certifi==2024.7.4
cffi==1.17.0
chardet==3.0.4
charset-normalizer==3.3.2
cryptography==43.0.0
Django==4.2.15
django-cors-headers==4.4.0
djangorestframework==3.10.3
drf-jwt==1.19.2
future==0.18.2
idna==2.8
macholib==1.15.2
pycparser==2.22
PyJWT==2.9.0
requests==2.32.3
six==1.15.0
sqlparse==0.4.4
typing_extensions==4.8.0
urllib3==1.25.11```

have jwt in ```utils.py```
```from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
import json
import jwt
import requests

def jwt_get_username_from_payload_handler(payload):
    username = payload.get('sub').replace('|', '.')
    authenticate(remote_user=username)
    return username
... more code in file

and in views.py

# Create your views here.
from functools import wraps
import jwt

from django.http import JsonResponse

def get_token_auth_header(request):
    """Obtains the Access Token from the Authorization Header
    """
    auth = request.META.get("HTTP_AUTHORIZATION", None)
    parts = auth.split()
    token = parts[1]

    return token
... more code


The error message indicates that jwt module is not found. Try activating the correct virtual environment and try to reinstall the module PyJWT

Thanks for the quick response, @13Tracso !  I did "python3 -m venv env" then "source env/bin/activate" then "pip install -r requirments.txt", all installed without issue. Still getting the same issue :-(

I'm a frontend engineer trying to learn backend even deeper. So I will explain it through that lens to help anyone else in that similar situation.
pip is similar to npm
requirements.txt is similar to package.json
Better explanation here:
Is npm in Node like virtualenv in Django?
I have python 3.9 installed as well as 3.11.5
I was running the virtual environment with python manage.py runserver which was running python 3.9, however when I used python3 manage.py runserver, which uses 3.11.5 all worked as expected.
Days of coding lost, but lots learned about virtual environments. This thread here helped lead to the solution: https://discuss.python.org/t/python3-v3-x-vs-python-v3-x/29087
